# feeding search params through a redirect_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I'm trying to pull a search parameter from my view to another view after I do a redirect_to in my Rails controller. I can get it working by forcing in the text to my parameter in the controller but I cannot get the data to pull in automatically.

I need this code below ("health" replaced with params[:search] data) please.

```
def index
 if params[:search].present?
  redirect_to search_courses_path(:search => "health")
 else
  @courses = Course.all
 end
end
```

My view on Index page

```
<div class="search-bar is-desktop">
  <form id="search_form">
     <%= label_tag search_courses_path, method: :get, class: "custom-input" do %>
      <%= search_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search By Keyword" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, form: "search_form", class: "search-btn" %>
   </form>
</div>
```

My search action in the courses controller

```
def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @courses = Course.search(params[:search])
    else
      @courses = Course.all
    end
end
```

Thanks for any help on these. I've been trying all sorts of parameter passing but not getting anywhere with it really. The best i've gotten is knowing how to hardcode the result into my redirect_to path. I know it's something basic i'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Answered this myself. This wasn't working before hand for some reason. Checked it again and got it to work.

 redirect_to search_courses_path(:search => params[:search])

Comment: I was going to ask you for the `search` method in your model.

Comment: My course model just uses 

searchkick

One thing I do notice with searchkick is that if I try search again it will only search the results displayed on the page and not search from the database again. Trying to figure this now.

Comment: Oops, I did my own search, I haven't used searchkick before :c

Comment: No worries Sebastian, thanks for the help. I'll have a good thinker at it before I put it up for the masses to have a peak. :D